# How to change the default debug Profile when launching multiple asp .NET core projects?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, iis

I have a solution that launches multiple projects, and I set the launch profile for both to the console app instead of launching in IIS via the Project `Properties` page.

When I launched the projects individually they launched successfully in the console windows. But when I set multiple startup projects they went back to launching in IIS.

How can I get multiple projects to launch using the correct debug profile?

Answer (score 13):

To set the default launch profile you can re-arrange the debug profiles listed in Properties > `launchSettings.json`. The first profile in the list will be the one used when launching multiple projects.

[image]

Comment: Does this work the next time you start debugging, or do you have to reload the project or the solution?

Comment: I believe it's effective immediately.

Comment: It looks like it's not working this way. Visual Studio just remembers last choosed profile but if there are no last used profile it seems to prefer the profile with commandName == "IISExpress".

Comment: @AlexDEV.pro when launching a single project that might be true, but this is for having multiple launch projects at once, where VS doesnt track last used profile.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be true in VS2022. It just uses whatever profile was last used when running a single project.

Comment: launchsettings.json uses ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT as a key for the configuration in the appsettings.json file. This is a serious limitation where a custom configuration can't be applied in addition to the built-in one such as development or production.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in the comment of the other answer, it doesn't seems to be true for VS2022. It does not automatically use the first entry in the `launchSettings.json` list.

You can change the starting project to a single one and switch the debug profile with the small arrow next to the play button in the toolbar one by one. But if you need to do a mass switch, I suggest doing a "search in all files", it's stored in the `.csproj.user` files:

`<ActiveDebugProfile>Docker</ActiveDebugProfile>`

Change them all, then reload your solution.